# How can I reboot or shutdown the system in an EFI or UEFI shell?

Tags: uefi, reboot, efi, poweroff

Having consulted resources related to the [commands available in a UEFI/EFI shell](http://www.opslib.com/2012/01/efi-shell-commands.html), I cannot find two commands I would expect to be available:

1. *reboot*
2. *poweroff*, *halt*, or *shutdown*

What am I missing here? (can it be that the EFI shell is somewhat overengineered, but lacks basic functionality?)

Comment: What’s wrong with Ctrl+Alt+Del or pushing the power button?

Comment: @DanielB I am aware of those options. However most GNU/Linux systems I used came with those handy things like commands like `shutdown`, `poweroff` and `reboot` and would have though the functionality they provide to be mirrored in EFI shell. So what you suggest is that those commands do not exit, is there a reference to that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The command `reset` will do both poweroff and reboot.  From the [UEFI Shell Specification](https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_Shell_2_2.pdf)

> **reset**
>
> **Summary**
>
> Resets the system.
>
> **Usage**
>
> reset [-w|-s|-c [string]] [-fwui]
>
> **Options**
>
> -s
>
> - Performs a shutdown
>
> -w
>
> - Performs a warm boot
>
> -c
>
> - Performs a cold boot
>
> string
>
> - String to be passed to reset service
>
> -fwui
>
> If the system firmware supports it, perform a reset back to the firmware user
> interface (FW UI)

> **Examples**
>
> To shut down the system:
>
> `Shell> reset -s`
>
> To cold reset the system and stop boot at the firmware user interface:
>
> `Shell> reset –c -fwui`